# convert result query into string

Tags: java, sql, database

I want to convert result query into String to use in my java code..
can anyone help ?
tq

code::

```
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT password FROM USER WHERE UserID='"+txtUserId.getText()+"';"); 
    pass.add(rs.getString("password"));


    st.close();
    //rs.close();
    con.close();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Could Not Connect to Database");
    }
```

Comment: I hope this is just example and your real code isn't looking like this. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You need `rs.next()` cursor to move forward for `ResultSet` data.

```
 while(rs.next()){
   pass.add(rs.getString("password"));
 }
```

Comment: it stated the method add(String) is undefined for the type String.. how to solve this ?

Comment: I was think pass is List. What is the the type of pass? If it is String than use `pass= rs.getString("password");`.

Comment: i have use pass=rs.getString("password"); when i use system.out.println(pass).. it print null..

Answer (score 0):

`executeQuery` returns a `ResultSet` - you can then navigate through the ResultSet to obtain the values returned by the statement/query

Example here

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
    throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
                   "SALES, TOTAL " +
                   "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                               "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                               "\t" + total);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
You want to get multiple value mean use

```
while(rs.next()){
   pass.add(rs.getString("password"));
 }
```

You want to get single value

```
if(rs.next()){
   pass.add(rs.getString("password"));
 }
```

Comment: it stated the method add(String) is undefined for the type String.. how to solve this ?